# Using react-leaflet together with leaflet-editable

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet, leaflet-editable

Is there a way to correctly use these libs together? I have to use the `ref` attribute to get the instance of the circle and then use this
`this.circle.enableEdit(this.map);`

Also it crashes on the first rerender of the page. The cirle stays, but the move control only moves. Like this

[image]

Comment: Please, provide a working codesandbox example

Comment: Which example do you want to implement in react because there are several like [basic controls](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.Editable/example/index.html), [Continue line by ctrl/command-clicking on first/last point](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.Editable/example/continue-line.html) etc